# How to find all Changed/added files in SVN after extracting them from the repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to SVN and I am trying to create a accelerator pack from a software package. On july 30th, I downloaded a web application package from SVN repository. Thereafter, I and my colleagues made multiple changes to the code base.

How do I list down  only the files that have been changed/added from July 30th? Is there an SVN command to list all such files? I tried going to each and every folder(and subfolder) and did a right click "show log" to see if there has been any changes made since July 30th but there are a lot of such folders and subfolders. Is there a quicker way to identify only the changed and added files in SVN after my first check out on July 30th

Answer (score 1):

Right click at the top of the working copy and select TortoiseSVN -> Check for Modifications.

From the command line, run  `svn status` from the top of the working copy.

Comment: When you say top of the working copy, are you referring to a folder before the one where all the files are placed. Here is my folder structure C:\G\RR\CP\bin

Comment: Whatever folder was created when you checked out your working copy. The top level folder. I don't know in that path where your working copy starts, this is something you need to know. Look at the icon overlays and walk up the structure until they stop.